# Listbox not opening handler

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a menu in a listbox format where user chooses an option and then another uiapp is shown with the info they selected. I am having an issue here that when I opened google gives me an error that says Error encountered. An expected error occurred. I think it has to do with the setId part, if I remove one of the setId's the error doesnt happen. is this even possible?

```
 function doGet(e) {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Services"); 
 var dropDownList = app.createListBox().setName('list').setId('list');
 var infoLabel = app.createLabel('Scroll around to select the service   desired').setId('infoLabel');
 var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
 //addItem fills the list  
 dropDownList.addItem("Option 1").setId("add");
 dropDownList.addItem("Option 2");
 panel.add(dropDownList);
 panel.add(infoLabel);
 app.add(panel);
 var info = app.getElementById("add");
 var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('display2');
 info.addClickHandler(handler2);

 app.add(dropDownList);
 app.add(infoLabel);
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(app);
}


 function display2(e) {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var html = app.add(app.createHTML("<p><p><b>You have selected this option</b>  </p>")).setHeight(220).setWidth(220);

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(app);
 return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you deploying this as a web app or a script within a Spreadsheet?

If you are deploying this as a web app, then `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` will not work - replace it with `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` where id is your spreadsheet ID which you will find in the URL when you open the file in the browser.

If you want to deploy this w/in a spreadsheet through a menu item or a simple button, then that works as is.

I was able to just copy paste your code and get the listbox part working fine -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkJNj_IM2wiPdHRYQThlaGVVSk04R052ZGNqclhEZWc#gid=0

---

**Update -**

I now understand what you are trying to do. Couple of things - you want to make sure you are adding a callback element via `handler.addCallbackElement(myWidget)` otherwise, you will not be able to read the value of the element. Second thing is that you don't need a server handler on each option in a dropdown list. Just having one handler will fire it for every change and you'll be able to get the option you selected.

I've cleaned up the code here below and also updated the spreadsheet to use this code.

```
function showUI() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("GeekSquad Services"); 

  var infoLabel = app.createLabel('Scroll around to select the service desired');

  var dropDownList = app.createListBox().setName('list').setId('list');
  dropDownList.addItem("Option 1");
  dropDownList.addItem("Option 2");
  //you can add as many options here manually or dynamically

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('dropDownCallback')
  handler.addCallbackElement(dropDownList);
  dropDownList.addClickHandler(handler);

  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();  
  panel.add(dropDownList);
  panel.add(infoLabel);
  app.add(panel);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}


function dropDownCallback(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var html = app.add(app.createHTML("<b>You have selected this option</b> " + e.parameter.list));

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}
```

**Update #2 -**

If you want to fork off and create different app instances thats easy (though its unclear why wouldn't just change panels).

```
    function dropDownCallback(e) {
      if(e.parameter.list === 'Option 1'){
        var app = UiApp.createApplication();
        var html = app.add(app.createHTML("Here for option!"));

        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        spreadsheet.show(app);
      }
      else if (e.parameter.list ==== 'Option 2'){
        //create and show other App here or whatever else
      }
      //refactor this better to not repeat code. 
    }
```